# Calling InitializeComponent in constructor every time?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have two constructors, how can i call InitializeComponent() method for both constructor.

For Example

class ABC

{

```
   public ABC(int a, int b)
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      //some Code
   }

  public ABC(int a, int b, int c)
  {
      InitializeComponent();
      // some Code
  }
```

}

Shall I Write like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your snippet of code looks fine to me. By this InitializeComponent() method would be invoked from both the constructors (either way the object may be created).

If you are sure, you need to call InitializeComponent() irrespective of the constructor, then u can even call it after the object creation to avoid duplication, but again it all depends on your logic and requirement implementation

Vinod

Comment: Hi Vinod Thanks For your Response, But whenever i called like this, I got a NullReferenceException was Raised. could you please provide me some information Regarding This?

Answer (score 4):

```
public ABC()
{
      InitializeComponent();
}

public ABC(int a, int b): this()
{
}

public ABC(int a, int b, int c): this(a,b)
{
}
```